# nodejs then() function executed before promise resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a problem with making Promise working as expected. I need to do following thing:

I get file names from stdout, split them into line and copy them. When copy operation is finished i want to start other operations and here is my problem.

I've created a copy function inside Promise, in case of error i reject it immediately, if thereare no errors i resolve it after copy in loop is finished but for some reason the function inside then() gets executed before copy operation is done

```
var lines  = stdout.split(/\r?\n/);

copyUpdatedFiles(lines).then(
    function() {
       console.log('this one should be executed after copy operation');
    }
);

function copyUpdatedFiles(lines) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        for (var i = 0; i < linesLength; i++) {
            fs.copy(lines[i], target, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    reject();
                }
            });
        }
        resolve();
    });
}
```

Please help cause i'm clearly missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It gets resolved as soon as you call `resolve`, which you're doing after *starting* the copies but before they *finish*. You have to wait for the last callback before you `resolve`. That means keeping track of how many you've see, see the `***` comments:

```
function copyUpdatedFiles(lines) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var callbacks = 0;                              // ***
        for (var i = 0; i < linesLength; i++) {
            fs.copy(lines[i], target, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    reject();
                } else {                                // ***
                    if (++callbacks == lines.length) {  // ***
                        resolve();                      // ***
                    }                                   // ***
                }                                       // ***
            });
        }
    });
}
```

---

Alternately, there are a couple of libraries out there that promise-ify NodeJS-style callbacks so you can use standard promise composition techniques like `Promise.all`. If you were using one of those, you'd just do *something* this:

```
function copyUpdatedFiles(lines) {
    return Promise.all(
        // CONCEPTUAL, semantics will depend on the promise wrapper lib
        lines.map(line => thePromiseWrapper(fs.copy, line, target))
    );
}
```

---

Side note: Your loop condition refers to a variable `linesLength` that isn't defined anywhere in your code. It should be `lines.length`.

Comment: To be more specific, you cannot reject and resolve a promise multiple times, so if you resolve it resolve it once, and if you reject in a for, reject + break or some other way to do it.

Comment: @atrifan: The problem isn't the repeated calls, it's making the first call too soon. (Calling reject/resolve repeatedly is pointless, but isn't the root cause of the issue here.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't wait for the copy to success before resolving the promise, after the `for`, all `fs.copy` has been put in the call stack, but  they didn't complete.

You can either use a counter inside the callback of `fs.copy` and call resolve once every callback has been called, or use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

```
var async = require('async');
var lines  = stdout.split(/\r?\n/);

copyUpdatedFiles(lines).then(
    function() {
       console.log('this one should be executed after copy operation');
    }
);

function copyUpdatedFiles(lines) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        async.map(lines, (line, callback) => {
            fs.copy(line, target, (err) => {
                callback(err);
            });
        },
        (err) => {
            if(err) {
                reject();
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}
```